# Why can't EXWM manage native macOS applications?

Tags: osx, x11, exwm

I have been using a Macbook Air M1 for professional reasons and I would like to amplify Emacs in my life.

One thing I have been searching for is the introduction of EXWM in my workflow. Unfortunately, as I started [reading the official documentation](https://github-wiki-see.page/m/ch11ng/exwm/wiki/Installation-on-macOS) I found out that there are some limitation when using EXWM in macOS.

In particular:

> Note that EXWM cannot manage native macOS applications at all, only X11 applications will be managed.

Why can't EXWM  manage native macOS applications while X11 applications are handled?

Comment: Because native macOS applications don't use X11, but Quartz.

Comment: If your goal is to use EXWM in macOS, run a GNU/Linux distribution in a virtual machine.

Comment: thanks, @aadcg. And why can't EXWM handle Quartz? What is so special about it?

Comment: I think theoretically it is possible, but I'm not sure. If it's not done it's because it either hard or impossible.

Comment: Notice that EXWM is a window manager for X11. Since macOS doesn't use X11, it's clearly outside its scope :)